# updating the data in access file when adding or deleteing it from c#

Tags: c#, database

i have a project connection between c# and access 2007 when adding or deleting any data through the interface of c# program there isn't any change in my base database,there isn't any error.
please help me ...

Comment: Can you post some of you code?

Comment: this.Validate();
            this.جدول1BindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.nDataSet);